# How to organise layers/groups in alphabetic oder in layers photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I've tried researching on the web but mostly people ask about adobe Premier and other softwares, theres is nothing I could find for photoshop.

My situation is this, I'm designing the Jersey shirts for the australian Super Rugby Teams. I've made all the folders for each team but forgot to put them in a alphabetical order.

My question is: **Is there a way to sort the folders in a alphabetic order?**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a script from Trevor Morris called Sort Layers, and it works perfectly. It sorts all layers/groups alphanumerically.

You can find, download, and read more about the script on Trevor's website: http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/scripts/sort-layers.html

Comment: As an update - This script is still there, and it still works, as of Photoshop CC 19.1.5 Thanks Tommy, and Trevor Morris Photographics.